# Deploy magento package design view in user's theme

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, phtml, magento-connect

I created a module on magento connect and I have a question about it. How to do to tell magento connect to deploy my module'views (phtml files) into my user's magento folder?

Maybe it's a stupid question but I did not find any answer to this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you create the connect package you define the directories and files which are part of your extension.  Wherever they reside when you create the package, this is where they will end up on the users install.  If you are asking about how to know where to put theme files in the package, as long as you are using a directory structure that doesn't conflict with core files, putting your theme files in `base/default` will ensure they are always available regardless of the theme used.

Comment: thank you! And the same for adminhtml template, I use default/default?

Comment: You often only have have `default/default` for admin so yes that's fine.  If the answer above is correct can you mark it as accepted?